# Как засунуть f-string в список

Tags: python, list

В процессе работы появилась необходимость создать список шаблонов
Пример: colorpatterns   = ['000000', '{}0000', '00{}00', '0000{}', '{}{}00', '{}00{}', '00{}{}', '{}{}{}']
Но проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь взять шаблон список оказывается пустым.
Подскажите как при обращении к списку по индексу получать шаблон, и дальше применять к нему метод .format()

Comment: По описанию ничего не понятно. Но есть подозрение, что f-строки тут не причём, вы просто что-то не то с самим списком делаете. Приведите код, в котором проблема воспроизводится.

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
colorpatterns = [f'000000', f'{{}}0000', f'00{{}}00', f'0000{{}}', f'{{}}{{}}00', f'{{}}00{{}}', f'00{{}}{{}}', f'{{}}{{}}{{}}']
 
for i in colorpatterns:
    print(i.format(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Необходимость тут f-строк вызывает сомнение :) Мб добавите вариант без них? :)

Comment: А чем вас f-строки не устроили? Я не вижу адекватного варианта без них.

Comment: 1. Действительно, зачем тут f-строки? 2. Форматирование с 3-мя аргументами, когда в строках 0, 1, 2 полей замены выглядит сомнительно.